# Camel FTP routing - two separate FTP filenames

Tags: apache-camel, spring-camel, camel-ftp

I have a Camel FTP route that has, in the body, a list of objects which I need to break up into multiple separate FTP transmissions with different FTP filenames.

I am thinking this should be a Splitter EIP pattern, however, I am not sure how to go about enabling the multiple separate FTP transmissions.

Example ...assuming I have 4 records in the Exchange ${body} which I wish to organize into 2 separate ftp transmissions, I can see how I could use code in a Process class to separate the body into 2 groups of records, however, the issue is how to then make this two separate FTP transmissions.

I have thought of bundling the different groups of records into separate Header or Property objects ( *in the Process class* ) but the issue is still the same ...how to subsequently process these Headers or Properties as two separate FTP transmissions.

I am considering using a  approach but I get the feeling there is a more elegant way using the  pattern.

I should note that ***I do not know*** in advance how many different groups of records ( *and thus how many separate FTP transmissions & filenames* ) I shall need ...in my example above there are 2, however, in reality there could could be many more.

Any thoughts or examples ?

By way of example ...lets assume following Process class to setup a sample Camel body:

```
class SetTestBody implements Processor {

    @Override
    void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {

        final String body = exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class)

        /**
         attribute6 is the -key- to use as the FTP filename ... all sttribute6 occurences of same value go
         to same ftp filename ...in example below, we would have 4 separate FTP file transfers ...

         one for the 2 entries having 2041,
         one for 6 entries having 2143,
         one for  2 entries having 2106
        */

        def r1 = [
                [ 'sku':'ALLO' , 'attribute3':'72','attribute4':'Local991','attribute5':'RosRen',   'attribute6':'2041' ],
                [ 'sku':'ALL2' , 'attribute3':'73','attribute4':'Local9910','attribute5':'RosRen',  'attribute6':'2143' ],
                [ 'sku':'ALL5O' , 'attribute3':'74','attribute4':'Local9911','attribute5':'RosRen', 'attribute6':'2143' ],
                [ 'sku':'ALL6O' , 'attribute3':'75','attribute4':'Local9912','attribute5':'RosRen', 'attribute6':'2143' ],
                [ 'sku':'ALL7O' , 'attribute3':'76','attribute4':'Local9913','attribute5':'RosRen', 'attribute6':'2143' ],
                [ 'sku':'ALL8O' , 'attribute3':'77','attribute4':'Local9914','attribute5':'RosRen', 'attribute6':'2041' ],
                [ 'sku':'ALL9O' , 'attribute3':'78','attribute4':'Local9915','attribute5':'RosRen', 'attribute6':'2106' ],
                [ 'sku':'ALL10O' , 'attribute3':'79','attribute4':'Local9916','attribute5':'RosRen','attribute6':'2143' ],
                [ 'sku':'ALL1O1' , 'attribute3':'80','attribute4':'Local9917','attribute5':'RosRen','attribute6':'2143' ],
                [ 'sku':'ALL1O2' , 'attribute3':'81','attribute4':'Local9918','attribute5':'RosRen','attribute6':'2106' ]
        ]

        // Sort the list so all entries are in proper sorted order ( sorted on attribute6 )
        def sortedBody = r1.sort{ a,b -> a['attribute6'] <=> b['attribute6']}

        exchange.getIn().setBody(sortedBody);

    }

}
```

Lets assume a sample route as follows:

```
<routes xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">

    <route id="rod-setTestBody-bean">

        <from uri="timer://fetchData?repeatCount=1"/>

        <log message="\n1 body is : ${body}\n"/>

        <process id="process1" ref="setTestBody"/>

        <log message="\n2 body is : ${body}\n"/>

        <split>
           <simple>${body}</simple>
           <log message="\nBody after split is : ${body}\n"/>

            <!--
            I would like to send all records of same attribute6 value to a same ftp destination ...just with different filename
            ...all records for 2041 in 1 ftp transmission, all for 2106 in second ftp transmission, all for 2143 in third ftp transmission
            -->
           <to uri="mock:ftpDestination1"/>
        </split>

    </route>


</routes>
```

Comment: Add a [example] to illustrate your thoughts and considerations. Share your "Camel FTP route" as code. This way we can see instead "assuming" what you have.

Comment: I expanded the question to include the minimal route ...hope this helps clarify.